# Filter Product Collection by Child product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, collection, product-collection

I have situation like 2 attribute which is assign to child product

1) `person_height_from` and 2) `person_height_to` which has **DropDown** type attribute

which is only assign in child product but not assign in parent products,

I want to filter product collection in category page with this attribute

like `length = 175`

```
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('person_height_from', array('lteq' => $length));

 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('person_height_to', array('gteq' => $length));
```

Is this possible to get only those parent product in category page which child product assign above value

your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i did with 2 attribute of child products to search with inner query

```
$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

// check if  query is already in sql then no need to add per event
$cloneSelect = clone $collection->getSelect();
$wherePart = $cloneSelect->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
$excludedWherePart = 'AND (e.entity_id IN';
foreach ($wherePart as $key => $wherePartItem) {
    if (strpos($wherePartItem, $excludedWherePart) !== false) {
        return $this;
    }
}

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$_readAdapter = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$status = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'status');
$heightTo = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'person_height_to');
$heightFrom = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'person_height_from');
$categoryId = Mage::registry("current_category")->getId();
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$query = $_readAdapter->select()
    ->from(array('e' => $collection->getTable('catalog/product')),array())
    ->joinInner(array(
        'at_status' => $status->getBackendTable()),
        'at_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND at_status.store_id = 0 AND at_status.attribute_id = ' .$status->getAttributeId(),
        array()
    )
    ->joinInner(array(
        'at_stock' => $resource->getTableName('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
        'at_stock.product_id = e.entity_id AND at_stock.is_in_stock = ' . 1,
        array()
    )
    ->joinInner(array(
        'cat_index' => $collection->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')),
        'cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id = ' . $storeId . ' AND cat_index.category_id = ' . $categoryId,
        array()
    )
    ->joinInner(array(
        'at_person_height_to' => $heightTo->getBackendTable()),
        'at_person_height_to.entity_id = e.entity_id AND at_person_height_to.store_id = 0 AND at_person_height_to.attribute_id = ' . $heightTo->getAttributeId(),
        array()
    )
    ->joinInner(array(
        'at_person_height_from' => $heightTo->getBackendTable()),
        'at_person_height_from.entity_id = e.entity_id AND at_person_height_from.store_id = 0 AND at_person_height_from.attribute_id = ' . $heightFrom->getAttributeId(),
    array()
    )
    ->where(
        "e.type_id = 'simple' AND at_person_height_from.value <= " . $length . " AND at_person_height_to.value >= " . $length
    )
    ->join(
        array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),
        'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id', array('parent_id')
    );

$productIds =  array_map('intval', array_unique($_readAdapter->fetchCol($query)));

// add filter here with parent ids
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

Hope this will help to others and get better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'length', 'like' => '175')
        )
    );

$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),
        'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
        array('product_id', 'parent_id')
    );

$collection->getSelect()->group('link_table.parent_id');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $productIds[] = $product->getParentId();
}

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

In above code first of all I have find child products which have length is 175. After that I have find parent id associated with child product then filter product collection according to parent product Ids.

Comment: is this possible to do in only 1 sql query, i have more then 1 lac product in store, it will huge effect on performance to get this collection :(

Comment: it's only for child of configurable product, not include bundle & group